# Take too long time to write in to Access Data Base using C# WPF application, Visual Studio,

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a WPF application using C# and VS.
And I am using an Access database.
I have a loop that has to run in a maximum time of 500MS, But its take 570+-

In my program, I have a wait time of ~340MS in total and more ~160MS that I can to optimize

After checking with a Stopwatch I found that when I write my data to my Access Database Its take about ~50MS (I have a 3 writes to there).
And I have no Idea how to optimize my Database write

My Class that connect and using the database is an external DLL file
that look like that (I also give an example of one method that take a 50MS of runtime, named as "AddDataToLocalHeaderResult"):

```
    namespace DataBaseManager
    {
        public class LocalPulserDBManager
        {
            private string localConnectionString;
            private string databaseName = $@"C:\Pulser\LocalPulserDB.mdb";
            private  readonly int _30DaysBack = -30;

            private static readonly Lazy<LocalPulserDBManager> lazy =new Lazy<LocalPulserDBManager>(() => new LocalPulserDBManager());

            public static LocalPulserDBManager LocalPulserDBManagerInstance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

            private void CreateConnectionString()
            {
                localConnectionString = $@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={databaseName};Persist Security Info=True";
            }

            private LocalPulserDBManager()
            {
                CreateConnectionString();
            }

public  void AddDataToLocalHeaderResult(string reportNumber,string reportDescription, 
            string catalog,string workerName,int machineNumber, Calibration c,string age)
        {
            if (IsHeaderLocalDataExist(reportNumber, catalog, machineNumber, c) == false)
            {
                using (OleDbConnection openCon = new OleDbConnection(localConnectionString))
                {
                    string query = "INSERT into [HeaderResult] ([ReportNumber],[ReportDescription],[CatalogNumber], " +
                        "[WorkerName], [LastCalibrationDate], [NextCalibrationDate], [MachineNumber], [Age]) " +
                        "VALUES (@report ,@reportDescription ,@catalog, @workerName," +
                        " @LastCalibrationDate, @NextCalibrationDate, @machineNumber, @age)";

                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", reportNumber);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportDescription", reportDescription);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catalog", catalog);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workerName", workerName); 
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastCalibrationDate", c.LastCalibrationDate);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextCalibrationDate", c.NextCalibrationDate);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineNumber", machineNumber);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
                        command.Connection = openCon;
                        openCon.Open();
                        int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        openCon.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ....
    ....
    METHODS
    .... 

        }
    }
```

In my executable program I use that like that :

I have usings as that :  `using static DataBaseManager.LocalPulserDBManager;`

and in my code I exeute the method like that `LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.AddDataToLocalHeaderResult(ReportNumber, Date_Description,CatalogNumber, WorkerName, (int)MachineNumber, calibrationForSave, AgeCells);`

One of my access database table look like that :
[image]

One row in that table look like that:
[image]

50MS it is normal runtime in that situation? 
If here is missing any information please tell me...

********************* EDITING **************************

I have change my `AddDataToLocalHeaderResult` method as the first command told me 
I got the same result

```
public  void AddDataToLocalHeaderResult(string reportNumber,string reportDescription, 
            string catalog,string workerName,int machineNumber, Calibration c,string age)
        {
            if (IsHeaderLocalDataExist(reportNumber, catalog, machineNumber, c) == false)
            {
                using (OleDbConnection openCon = new OleDbConnection(localConnectionString))
                {
                    string query = "INSERT into [HeaderResult] ([ReportNumber],[ReportDescription],[CatalogNumber], " +
                        "[WorkerName], [LastCalibrationDate], [NextCalibrationDate], [MachineNumber], [EditTime], [Age]) " +
                        "VALUES (@report ,@reportDescription ,@catalog, @workerName," +
                        " @LastCalibrationDate, @NextCalibrationDate, @machineNumber,@edittime, @age)";
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime edittime = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);

                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", reportNumber);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportDescription", reportDescription);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catalog", catalog);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workerName", workerName); 
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastCalibrationDate", c.LastCalibrationDate);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextCalibrationDate", c.NextCalibrationDate);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineNumber", machineNumber);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edittime", edittime);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
                        command.Connection = openCon;
                        openCon.Open();
                        int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        openCon.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does it matter that the `AddDataToLocalHeaderResult` references 7 fields but the SQL has 8 and in different order?

Comment: @June7 I tried what you said, it does not work better for me...

Comment: Opening and closing the connection for each single INSERT is probably not good for performance.

Comment: What does `IsHeaderLocalDataExist` do and how long does it take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method you're showing here, you're adding one row at a time. So the server is opening a connection to the db, the data's being written to memory, then to the physical file (mdb), then the indexes are being updated. To that's a full four steps per row you're trying to execute. Worse than that, the data write to the physical file is time consuming.

I think that if you use a different approach, do these four steps (connection, memory, data write, re-index) for the entire set of data you're trying to insert. So, let's say you're adding 1000 records, rather than 4000 steps (4x1000), you could reduce this processing to 1400 processing steps (1 connection, super-fast 1000 memory writes, 1 data file write, 1 index revision).

The following code gives the rough idea of what I'm talking about:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //memory-only list for data loading
        List<HeaderResult> mylist = new List<HeaderResult>(){ new HeaderResult("report1","desc of report","ete"), new HeaderResult("report2", "desc of report2", "ete2")};
        var tableForInsert = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from  HeaderResult", "my conneciton string")) {
            dataAdapter.Fill(tableForInsert);

            //now I have a live copy of the table into which I want to insert data
            //blast in the data
            foreach (HeaderResult hr in mylist) {
                tableForInsert.Rows.Add(hr);
            }

            //now all the data is written at once and sql will take care of the indexes after the datat's written
            dataAdapter.Update(tableForInsert);
        }
}

//class should have same fields as your table
class HeaderResult
{
    string report;
    string reportDescription;
    string etc;
    public HeaderResult(string rpt, string desc, string e)
    {
        report = rpt;
        reportDescription = desc;
        etc = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be an mdb file, not mdf. I think any answer should stick to the original database MS Access (although recommending not to use it wouldn't go amiss).